# generate RSA signature using Security Transforms and validate using OpenSSL/C++

Tags: c++, cocoa, openssl, rsa

I am trying to implement a feature where Linux server sends random data along with some certificate info (like subject or issue) to the OSx client and OSx client gets the certificate from the Keychain store, filters based on the certificate info, extract the private key and sign the random data with SHA256 algorithm.

Client then sends base64 encoded certificate and signed data (base64 encoded) back to the server. Linux server using OpenSSL library (get public key from certificate) to validate the signed data.

The problem I am facing is server is not enable to validate the signed data whereas for windows client, Server is able to validate signed data.

I am using the below Security API on macOS (10.13.4)

```
std::string osxPrivateKey::signData(const uint8_t* pData, uint32_t nDataSize, vector<uint8_t>& aSignature) {
    const char* str = (const char*)pData;
    unsigned char *result = new unsigned char[CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_SHA256(str, strlen(str), result);

    CFDataRef myData = CFDataCreate(NULL, result, CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH);
    CFErrorRef error;

    osxObject<SecTransformRef> signer;
    SecTransformRef signerRef = SecSignTransformCreate(m_oKey.get(), &error);
    signer.set(signerRef);

    //SecTransformSetAttribute(signer.get(), kSecTransformDebugAttributeName, kCFBooleanTrue, &error);
    SecTransformSetAttribute(signer.get(), kSecTransformInputAttributeName, myData, &error);
    //SecTransformSetAttribute(signer.get(), kSecInputIsAttributeName , kSecInputIsPlainText, &error);
    SecTransformSetAttribute(signer.get(), kSecInputIsAttributeName , kSecInputIsDigest, &error);
    //SecTransformSetAttribute(signer.get(), kSecInputIsAttributeName , kSecInputIsRaw, &error);
    SecTransformSetAttribute(signer.get(), kSecPaddingKey, kSecPaddingPKCS1Key, &error);
    //SecTransformSetAttribute(signer.get(), kSecPaddingKey, kSecPaddingPKCS5Key, &error);
    SecTransformSetAttribute(signer.get(), kSecEncodeLineLengthAttribute, kSecLineLength64, &error);
    SecTransformSetAttribute(signer.get(), kSecDigestTypeAttribute, kSecDigestSHA2, NULL);

    int digestLength = 256;
    CFNumberRef dLen = CFNumberCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kCFNumberIntType, &digestLength);
    SecTransformSetAttribute(signer.get(), kSecDigestLengthAttribute, dLen, &error);
    CFRelease(dLen);

    CFDataRef signature = (CFDataRef)SecTransformExecute(signer.get(), &error);


    unsigned char* signData = new unsigned char[1024];
    int size = CFDataGetLength(signature);
    CFDataGetBytes(signature, CFRangeMake(0,CFDataGetLength(signature)), (UInt8*)(signData));

    char* encodeBase64SignData = new char[1024];
    //internal library to convert binary to base64 encoding
    hc::encodeBase64((const char*)signData, size, encodeBase64SignData, 1023);
    encodeBase64SignData[1023] = '\0';

    delete encodeBase64SignData;
    delete signData;

    return string(encodeBase64SignData);
}
```

On Server, following code is used for validating the signature

```
bool verifySignature(const EVP_PKEY * pkey, const BLOB & data, const BLOB & signature, size_t signatureLen, DSStr & strErr)
{
    bool     result = false;
    EVP_MD_CTX* ctx = NULL;
    {// scope
        OSSL_CHECK(ctx = EVP_MD_CTX_create());
        const EVP_MD* md = NULL;;
        OSSL_CHECK(md = EVP_get_digestbyname("SHA256"));
        OSSL_CHECK(EVP_DigestInit_ex(ctx, md, NULL) == 1);
        OSSL_CHECK(EVP_DigestVerifyInit(ctx, NULL, md, NULL, (EVP_PKEY*)pkey) == 1);
        if (EVP_PKEY_id((EVP_PKEY*)pkey) == EVP_PKEY_RSA) {
            OSSL_CHECK(EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_padding(ctx->pctx, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING) == 1);

        }
        OSSL_CHECK(EVP_DigestVerifyUpdate(ctx, &data[0], data.size()) == 1);
        ERR_clear_error();
        OSSL_CHECK(EVP_DigestVerifyFinal(ctx, (unsigned char*)&signature[0], signatureLen) == 1);
        result = true;
    }// scope
OSSL_CHECK_failed:
    if (ctx)  EVP_MD_CTX_destroy(ctx);
    return result;
}
```

Since I am new to macOS, I am not sure if I am missing anything. I really appreciate any help as I am blocking on this from a week.

Answer (score 0):

You took in a parameter called `pHash`, then hashed it into `result`.  If it was already a hash you've double-hashed, which would definitely give you the wrong signature.

Further, you hashed it using `strlen(pHash)` as the length, completely ignoring the `nHashSize` parameter.

Since your function is named `signHash` and the parameter is named `pHash`, one suspects that you instead meant

```
CFDataRef myData = CFDataCreate(NULL, pHash, nHashSize);
```

Comment: I was trying couple of things. First I provide hash to the function and then later change it to plain data. Maybe name is confusing, I will edit it to make it more clear. Thanks for the suggestion.